Python commands work in console but not in script
Brand new to blender but not to Python. I have a simple script where I import an STL, translate it, apply physics settings, play the animation, and do a quick render. If I run each line of code one-by-one by copy-pasting into the console it works flawlessly. If I run it as a script it will still render, but either the animation does not play or the render is done on the first frame (object still in air).
I've checked the console output, and there are no errors.
resolution = 1024
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = resolution
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = resolution

#bpy.context.scene.frame_start = 1
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)


# Load STL
model_path = '91292A337_18-8 Stainless Steel Socket Head Screw.stl'
bpy.ops.wm.stl_import(filepath=os.path.abspath(os.path.join('STL',model_path)))
obj = bpy.context.active_object


# Apply initial transformations

#bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)
obj.rotation_euler = (random.random()*6.283, random.random()*6.283, 0)

obj.location[0] = 0
obj.location[1] = 0
obj.location[2] = 0.2    # units are wayyyyy off for some reason

val = 1/500
mesh = obj.data
scale_matrix = Matrix.Diagonal((val,val,val,val))
mesh.transform(scale_matrix)

# Apply physics settings to object
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add()
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.type = 'ACTIVE'

# Drop object
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(30)
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.abspath('test.png')
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

# Delete object
bpy.ops.object.delete()
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.data.meshes.remove(obj.data)
    


Why exactly do you need the call to screen.animation_play()?

Long story short I want the object to be lying flat on a surface. The only way I could think of to reliably do this without any complex maths was to have the object fall and let gravity settle the rest.

Okay, well your problem is that when you run this all at once in a dedicated script it runs each line essentially instantaneously, in sequence. So it's not like it's "pressing play" and then letting the simulation run, and then moving to the next line of code, it's pressing play and then immediately moving to the next line. You would probably want to bake down the rigid body simulation to keyframes if you want something more predictable.
